# Using Bootstrap Modal as Register and Login Form. On error the full page is served

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, redirect, bootstrap-modal

I am using jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js to load Login and Register form from their url as Modals using the code below:

```
<script>
$(function ($, undefined) {
    
    // log in & sign up buttons
    $(".register-btn").modalForm({
      
      modalID: "#registerModal",
      
      formURL: "/register-modal/",
    
    });
    
});

$(function ($, undefined) {
    
    // log in & sign up buttons
    $(".login-btn").modalForm({
      
      modalID: "#registerModal",
      
      formURL: "/login-modal/",
    
    });
    
});

$(function ($, undefined) {
    
    // log in & sign up buttons
    $(".forgot-password").modalForm({
      
      modalID: "#registerModal",      
      formURL: "/recover-modal/",
    
    });
    
});
</script>
```

HTML code for the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:400px;">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="registerModalLabel">Register</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Modal Code :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


 {% block title %} Login {% endblock %}
 {% block style %}
 

 {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}  
  
 <div class="container-fluid ">
    
    <div class="row ">  
        
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            
            
            <form class="account-register form-narrow p-3 mb-4 bg-white" id="login_form" method="POST"
                action="" autocomplete="off">
                {% if messages %}
            <div id="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info"
                    role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                        aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    {{ message|escape }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            <div id="messages">
                {% for message in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger"
                    role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                        aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    {{ message|escape }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
                <div class="text-center">
                  <h4><i class="fa fa-lock fa-3x"></i></h4>
                </div>
                <h4 class="text-center mb-5">Login </h4>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group{% if form.username.errors %} has-error{% endif %}" >
                    <label class="control-label" for="id_username">Email Address</label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="id_username" maxlength="150" name="username"  pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" type="text" required />
                    <div class="error-block">{{ form.username.errors }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group{% if form.password.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="id_password">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="id_password" name="password" type="password" required />
                    
                    <div class="error-block">{{ form.password.errors }}</div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="g-recaptcha mb-2" data-sitekey="6LebmPsZAAAAADT_1QjnC70TJ2aiBX1a9rqWmhev"
                style="transform:scale(1.1);-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;">
               </div>
                
                <button type="submit" name="login"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block text-uppercase shadow-4 mb-4" >
                Login<i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                
                <br/>
                
                <p class="text-center">
                    Don't have an account?<button type="button" class="register-btn a btn btn-link" style="font-size:14px; margin-top:-4px;">Register </button>
                </p>
                <br/>
                <p class="text-center text-primary">

                    <button  type="button" class="forgot-password a btn btn-link" style="font-size:14px; text-decoration:none;">Forgot user ID and/or password? </button> 
                </p>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

<!-- /container -->

 {% endblock %}

 {% block scripts %}
 <script src="{% static 'js/toggle.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/floating-wpp.min.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.js' %}"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'js/qoc_home.js' %}"></script>
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
 
 <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js' %}"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#login_form").on("submit", function(){
    $("#pageloader").css('visibility', 'visible');
  });//submit
});

$(function ($, undefined) {
    
    // log in & sign up buttons
    $(".register-btn").modalForm({
      
      modalID: "#registerModal",      
      formURL: "/register-modal/",
    
    });
    
});



$(function ($, undefined) {
    
    // log in & sign up buttons
    $(".forgot-password").modalForm({
      
      modalID: "#registerModal",      
      formURL: "/recover-modal/",
    
    });
    
});
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

LoginView Code

```
class LoginViewModal(FormView):
    template_name = 'login-modal.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = '/dashboard'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect ("/dashboard")
        else:
            return super(LoginViewModal, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
            
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        if (self.request.user.is_authenticated) and (self.request.user.user_type==4):
            return redirect('/dashboard')
        else:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Use this to add extra context."""       
        context = super(LoginViewModal, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'show_captcha' in self.request.session:
            show_captcha = self.request.session['show_captcha']
            context['show_captcha'] = True
        return context
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.login(self.request)        
        
        recaptcha_response = self.request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
        payload = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode()
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)

        # verify the token submitted with the form is valid
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        result = json.loads(response.read().decode())
        if result['success']:
            if user.two_factor_auth is False and (user.phone_number_verified is True):
                login(self.request, user) 
                try:
                    UserLog.objects.filter(username=user.id).update(failed_attempt=0)
                except Exception:
                    print("No failed attempts ")
                   
                return redirect('/dashboard')
            
            else:
                try:
                    response = send_verfication_code(user)
                    pass
                except Exception as e:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                                        'verification code not sent. \n'
                                        'Please retry logging in.')
                    return redirect('/login')
                data = json.loads(response.text)

                if data['success'] == False:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                                    data['message'])
                    return redirect('/login')

                
                if data['success'] == True:
                    self.request.method = "GET"
                    print(self.request.method)
                    kwargs = {'user':user}
                    return PhoneVerificationView(self.request, **kwargs)
                else:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                            data['message'])
                    return redirect('/login')
        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
            return redirect('/login')
```

When an error occurs in the form (for example if the user enters incorrect password. The modal redirects to /login-modal/ and a full page with login form is seen instead of returning to the same modal. What can I do in order to stay on the modal when error occurs ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, what you are trying to achieve here is that when a user enters incorrect credentials, for example, you want to show an error message on the page without having to reload so that the credentials are not lost? if that is the case, you must use AJAX/fetch API, I'd go for AJAX since you're already using jquery, you can send the data using jquery `$.post`

Implementing AJAX with Django is a bit complicated but a simple google search would do, [this](https://www.it.iitb.ac.in/frg/wiki/images/b/b5/Sanhita.Patil_LoginWebsiteAndJQueryInplaceEditingUsingAjax.pdf) tutorial explains how to implement a login and signup mechanism using ajax and Django.

Now if you just want to show the modal again when an error you could have an error variable as a boolean, with 0 being no errors and 1 being the opposite, and pass it to your front-end, and have a script tag in your HTML that will trigger the modal when there is an error.

Comment: All, I want it that when the form returns error, it should not redirect to /login-modal/ instead it should remain at / and error should be displayed inside the modal. Since I am loading a url inside the modal, or error it always redirects to /login-modal/

Comment: Yes, then you must use AJAX to verify the credentials and catch errors, and only redirect on success.

Comment: well I am validating my form on submit.

Comment: That's front-end verification, you need the actual server to verify everything and attempt to log the user in, without refreshing or redirecting except on success, and I do not see any AJAX in your code to do that.